# How do I include conditional formatting within a style attribute?

Tags: css, email, outlook, formatting, conditional-statements

Right now I'm coding an email and need to apply specific padding for Outlook 2007 and higher. At the moment I have the conditional formatting applied at the very end of the style attribute to override the "default" padding, like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="211" align="left" class="ending_soon_table" style="float: left; padding: 0 10px; <!--[if gte mso 12]>padding: 0 7px;<![endif]-->">
```

Any tips on how I should be formatting differently?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? 
Any fiddle for this?

Good practice is to use whole statement for padding:

```
<table style="padding: top right bottom left;"></table>
```

Not just top-bottom && right-left declaration.

Also try `!important` to make sure it override existing CSS (NOTE: use `!important` just for testing.)

Than your statement is used only for greater than mso(ffice) 12. Is that what you want or you need it above 2007 version?

In case you need above 2007, change it to:

```
<!--[if gte mso 7]>padding: 0 7px;<![endif]-->
```

More on this you got here: http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

It's a bad practice to have so much elements for styling email. Good thing is that you used table elements for it. Can you make a little snippet for your example please?